# Factory Girl Passing nil to user model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

Pretty simple, I am using factory girl to do the following:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    sequence :user_email do |n|
        "user#{n}@example.com"
    end

    # Allows for multiple user names
    sequence :user_name do |n|
        "user#{n}"
    end

    factory :user, class: Xaaron::User do
        first_name 'Adam'
        last_name 'Something'
        user_name {generate :user_name}
        email {generate :user_email}
        password 'somePasswordThat_Is$ecure10!'
    end
end
```

And from there we pass this information into the user modal:

```
require 'bcrypt'

module Xaaron
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :password

    before_save :encrypt_password

    validates :first_name, presence: true
    validates :user_name, uniqueness: true, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
    validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
    validates_uniqueness_of :user_name
    validates_uniqueness_of :email
    validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true, length: { minimum: 10 }, if: :new_record?

    def self.authenticate_user(user_name, password)
        user = Xaaron::User.find_by_user_name(user_name)
        if(user && user.password == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.salt))
            user
        else
            nil
        end
    end

    def encrypt_password
        if password.present?
            self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
            self.password = BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

From there, any test that tests the user password validation or seeing if the password we generate is the same one we store in the database **fails** because factory girl is passing **nil** to the database.

**Failed Test Output**

```
  5) Xaaron::User Validation checks should validate a user based on login credentials
     Failure/Error: Xaaron::User.authenticate_user(@user.user_name, @user.password).should == @user
       expected: #<Xaaron::User id: 5, first_name: "Adam", last_name: "Something", user_name: "user9", email: "user8@example.com", password: nil, salt: "$2a$10$Y1m4YK.4znWVz2icp0ENtO", created_at: "2014-04-06 15:20:53", updated_at: "2014-04-06 15:20:53">
            got: nil (using ==)
     # ./spec/models/xaaron/user_spec.rb:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

You can see in the above that: `password: nil` which it shouldn't be ...

**The Test that Generated the fail**

```
it "should validate a user based on login credentials" do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  Xaaron::User.authenticate_user(@user.user_name, @user.password).should == @user
end
```

**As requested - Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140323000123) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "xaaron_users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "user_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password"
    t.string   "salt"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you share the schema of User from `schema.rb`. Also, if you would like to discuss this on chat then join me at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Comment: @KirtiThorat I shared the schema for the engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `attr_accessor :password` from the class `User`. 
As ActiveRecord would treat it as a virtual attribute and it will not be saved in the database.

If you notice rspec failure message received:

```
expected: #<Xaaron::User id: 5, first_name: "Adam", last_name: "Something", user_name: "user9", email: "user8@example.com", password: nil, salt: "$2a$10$Y1m4YK.4znWVz2icp0ENtO", created_at: "2014-04-06 15:20:53", updated_at: "2014-04-06 15:20:53">
```

`password` is not saved in database. Make sure to remove the `attr_accessor` from the `User` model so `password` is treated as field and **would be saved in database.**

Next, you need to update the example as below:

```
it "should validate a user based on login credentials" do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  @login_user = FactoryGirl.build(:user) 
  Xaaron::User.authenticate_user(@user.user_name, @login_user.password).should == @user 
end
```

`@user` contains the actual record created in database, so `@user.password` has the encrypted password already. Your example fails because you are sending the encrypted password to `authenticate_user` method and **re-encrypting the already encrypted password** with:

```
BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.salt)
```

In reality, for your example to pass what you need to pass is the actual password **without any encryption.** That is why I added `@login_user` in your example.